# TinyMCE Format Painter Headings styles not being being applied

Tags: tinymce

When using the TinyMCE Format Painter plugin, we're seeing that heading formats aren't being transferred when doing a format copy/paster. Like, if a block is set to style "Heading 1", then that style is ignored when doing a format paint of the block.

Is there a setting we're missing to enable headings styles to be applied?

Thanks